# Chart.js animated on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with chart.js but I also would want to display the chart on scroll.

I am working with this code: [**DEMO 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/MU9aw/)

```
    var doughnutData = [
            {
                value: 30,
                color:"#F7464A"
            },

            {
                value : 120,
                color : "#4D5360"
            }

        ];


var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
```

But it appears always, not on scroll.

Looking arouond i saw this fiddle wich does the effect:
[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/TSmDV/61/)

But updating the following code to my first demo does not work: [DEMO 1 UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/MU9aw/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`doughnutData` instead `data`

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Pie(doughnutData);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MU9aw/2/)

In case you need a doghnut:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MU9aw/3/)

Comment: Works perfect! Just modified the last part of the code for: getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData); since I wanted the donut one, not the pie.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont wanna that restart every scroll, try this:

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function(){            
  $('.startChart').each(function(i){    
        var options = {
                animationEasing: 'easeOutQuart',        
                animationSteps: 150,
                segmentShowStroke: true,
                segmentStrokeColor: 'FFF'                   
        };
        var doughnutData = [
            {value: 30, color:"#F7464A"},               
            {value : 120,color : "#4D5360"}         
        ];
        var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData, options);
        $(window).unbind(i);
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MU9aw/74/