# Doughnut chart - interaction with specific segment of a chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to create a simple doughnut chart with chartjs. I've been digging through the Documentation and Stack (of course), but I couldn't find it.
Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/zyqtyna7/1/

```
<div class="place-for-chart">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<div class="description">
    <p class="first hide">I'm description to no. 1 and I was hide</p>
    <p class="second hide">I'm description to no. 2 and I was hide</p>
    <p class="third hide">I'm description to no. 3 and I was hide</p>
</div>
<script>
    var data = {
        datasets: [{
            data: [20, 20, 20],
            backgroundColor: ["#27ae60", "#95a5a6", "#488a99"]
            }],
        labels: ["first", "second", "third"],
    };

$(document).ready(
   function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var CompetenceChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: data 
});
})
```

I'm not sure, but I think that the biggest question is: how can I target a specific segment of a chart (and then do something with it)? I'm asking this, because my project requires that:

1. descriptions in paragraphs will be visible after user's click at related part of chart (how can I target this segment???);
2. tooltips will have only labels' name (no values) (I couldn't decipher the Documentation);
3. chart animation should be triggered with scroll (segments will appear in sequence after scrolling - is it even possible?)

I'll be very greatfull for any insight - I'm stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG! Now I know. It took me so many hours, but was so obvious! Here's my new - working - code: https://jsfiddle.net/m954jto4/ Documentation of Chartjs and same basic js script - that's all, what I needed (shame on me!).

```
<div class="place-for-chart">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<div class="description">
  <p class="first hidden" id="hide1">I'm description to no. 1 and I was hide</p>
  <p class="first hidden" id="hide2">I'm description to no. 2 and I was hide</p>
  <p class="first hidden" id="hide3">I'm description to no. 3 and I was hide</p>
</div>

var data = {
    datasets: [{
            data: [20, 20, 20],
            backgroundColor: ["#27ae60", "#95a5a6", "#488a99"]
            }],
        labels: ["first", "second", "third"],
};


$(document).ready(
function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: data,
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: true,
                onClick: (e) => e.stopPropagation(),
                position: 'left',
                labels: {
                    fontSize: 20
                    }
                },

            tooltips: {
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                            var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                            return label;
                                } 
                            }
                    },
            cutoutPercentage: 65
            }
        }
        );

canvas.onclick = function(event) {
    var activePoints = myNewChart.getElementsAtEvent(event);
    var hiddenparagraph1 = document.getElementById("hide1");
    var hiddenparagraph2 = document.getElementById("hide2");
    var hiddenparagraph3 = document.getElementById("hide3");

    if (activePoints.length > 0) {
        var clickedSegmentIndex = activePoints[0]._index;

    if (clickedSegmentIndex==0) {
        hiddenparagraph1.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
    else if(clickedSegmentIndex==1) {
        hiddenparagraph2.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
    else {
    hiddenparagraph3.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
    }


    };
    }
);
```

Comment: Woo, now i realize that i misunderstood your question .... Well GJ anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do 2 of 3.. and I found documentation on how to do the third one.. But I was not able to make it work :/.... (i will try again when i have a bit more of time).

So here is the JSfiddle with this modifications:

1:Data is shown on mouse click
2:On top labels are shown, but when you click you wont see any labels but a black mark

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yorknew45/380zvnuc/%22jsfiddle%22)

So what did I do?

```
options: {
    // This chart will not respond to mousemove, etc
    events: ['click'],
    tooltips: {
       callbacks: {
          label: function(tooltipItem) 
          {
             return tooltipItem.yLabel;
          }
                  }
              }
    }
```

I added the options part with those codes.

the **events:['click']** makes the labels show when you click a part of the chart instead of hovering it.

the **tooltips** with the **callbacks** "turn off" showing the labels on mouse click.

And for the other part that you ask, about showing the animation when you scroll to the part where the chart is I found this 2 links that tells you how to do so (I couldn't make it work, but I will try again when I have more time and update).

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772547/how-to-make-the-chart-js-animate-when-scrolled-to-that-section)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510088/chart-js-animated-on-scroll)

Please let me know if this is what you wanted to know! CHEERS!

Comment: Thanks for your insights, but they didn't solved my problem. I have two parts of code: description and doughnut chart that I want to combine.

Comment: I think that I need to do it in three steps: 
1. target specific part of my chart;
2. create an event action;
3. connect this event action with visibility of a paragraphs

Actually, since my previous post I've made some progress. My code looks right now a little different [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/wa6vpdhb/1/). I've somehow deciphered a Documentation of Chartjs;), so I can target a part of a chart and create an event, but I’m stuck with the third one – how to connect this event with visibility of the paragraps.